# Escaping escaping file_get_contents( ); and running a function in place

Tags: php, string, file, escaping

Im really lost at the moment what I need to do its open a file find !@#*function*#@! and run a php function in its place.

I've been using file_get_contents() to open the file and I have to go through at replace certain things. there is simple things like text I can go through and replace with just a simple str_replace(). what I need to do is run a function and let it out etc etc in place of !@#*function*#@! in the file string.

I hope this makes some sense Im struggling to explain it myself.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing a templating engine. I suggest taking a look at things like Smartie or Twig, which already do this. (either to use them instead to avoid re-inventing the wheel, or to read their code and learn from them if you do want to do it yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
$file = file_get_contents();

$newFile = preg_replace_callback('/(\!\@\#function\#\@\!)/is', 'yourfunction',$file);
```